# Combining data from Project Server and SharePoint into a single report

Tags: sharepoint, project-server

I need to combine data from the **Project Server reporting database** with data from **custom lists in SharePoint workspaces**. The results need to be displayed within a single report. How should this be done? Options I've thought of:

1. Extend the reporting database with the custom list data (if this is possible). Use Reporting Services to display the output.
2. Query the reporting database and the SharePoint workspaces and combine results in memory. Write custom code to display the output.

Any other ideas? I have the skills to develop this but am very open to purchasing a product if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this sort of problem as well.  My apporach:

1. Create a Custom reporting Db.
2. Run regular jobs from the SQL Server to query sharepoint (via WS) and store the results in the db.

   i use the ListItemsChangesSinceToken is Lists.asmx to improve effeciency. Also I utilise  the sitedataquery tool set. I wrote a really simple interface into it for the ability to call a sitedataquery remotely, returning a dataTable.
3. Use Reporting Services / any tool to extract and report on the data.

The reason I opted for a staging Db was for

1. Performance - the WS calls are pretty slow.
2. Service continuity - if SP is down for any reason or slow then queries will fail.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the tool [SharePoint Data Miner](http://www.i-pmo.com.au/Products/SharePointDataMiner.aspx) which appears to do the same as DJ's answer.